# PHP Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference // array_pop

Tags: php, standards, strict, php-5.6, php-5.2

Since i'm in PHP 5.6, i have this warning (not in PHP 5.2) :

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in blockcategories_top.php on line 157
```

Here is the line 157 :

```
line 155    if ($cookie->last_visited_category) {
line 156      $c = new Category(intval($cookie->last_visited_category));
line 157      $oldies = array_pop($c->getParentsCategories());
line 158      $oldies = $oldies['id_category'];
line 159      $smarty->assign('oldies', $oldies);
line 160    }
```

Please, how can i fix it ? :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just replace

```
$oldies = array_pop($c->getParentsCategories());
```

with

```
$oldies = $c->getParentsCategories();
$oldies = array_pop($oldies);
```

The warning happens because [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) expects the parameter to be a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), and function return values are not.

Comment: You rock ! Thank you so much ^^